# Let $\lambda>1$ and show the equation $\lambda - z -e^{-z} = 0$ has exacly one solution in the half plane $\{z:Re(z)>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\lambda>1$ and show the equation $\lambda - z -e^{-z} = 0$ has exacly one solution in the half plane $\{z:Re(z)>0\}$. Show that this solution must be real. What happens to the solution as $\lambda \rightarrow 1 $?

Comment: As phrased, this doesn't make a whole lot of sense, as there are no real points in the set $\{z:\Re{(z)}>0\}$

Comment: @JoshuaBiderman this exercise is the book Jonh B. Conway, Functions of One Complex Variable!

Comment: Maybe it says "Re(z)$\geq$ 0"? That would be more possible.

To show that this function has a real root is a simple application of the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @JoshuaBiderman The exercise is only > 0

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm sorry. I was misreading this as the imaginary part. No, it's saying the real part, and obviously there are real numbers with positive real part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for my misunderstanding previously. we have that $|\lambda-z|=e^{-\Re{(z)}}<1$ holds, if there are any solutions at all. Then you can apply Rouche's Theorem to $f(z)=e^{-z}$ and $g(z)=\lambda-z$. Since $g$ has only one solution, $f+g$ does inside this curve. To prove it is real, you can simply apply the intermediate value theorem. It shouldn't be hard to make the function positive and then negative.

An alternative fun and interesting approach, if you already knew that the solution was real, is as follows:

Applying the intermediate value theorem tells you there must be at least one solution. To see uniqueness, any solution satisfies: $\lambda=z+e^{-z}$. Since $\lambda>1$, we can write $\lambda=\alpha+\beta$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq\beta<1$. Partitioning $z=\gamma+\delta$ into an integer and fractional part as well, and setting $\alpha=\gamma$, tells us that any solution must satisfy $\beta=\delta+e^{-\alpha}e^{-\delta}$. But everything except for $\delta$ in this equation is known, so we have one equation with one unknown and so there are one, zero, or infinitely many solutions. Zero is impossible because the IVT gave us one, and infinite means that this equation is degenerate. By inspection it isn't, and so there is only one solution.

Comment: Your second method will not work in general, because if $c$ is sufficiently large then $x+ce^{-x}$ is not injective on $\mathbb{R}_+$. (The sum of an increasing and a decreasing function has a minimum. Appropriately weighting this sum will move the minimum to the left or right.) It is the fact that $e^{-\alpha} \leq 1$ that allows you to perform this trick.

Comment: Ah yes, I am relying on that deliberately, that's a good point that you need to have the additive factor less than 1. Thank you for highlighting it.

Comment: Could you define LaRoche's theorem?  Google doesn't give any results for anything by that name.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "Rouche's Theorem"